# Does there exist a sequence of augment paths such that backward edges are not needed?

Tags: algorithm, graph, max-flow, ford-fulkerson

I'm learning the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm, and I understand that we need backward edges because the augment path that we choose may not contribute to the final max flow. But I was wondering if there exists a sequence of augmenting paths such that backward edges are not needed? I've tried many examples and it seems there exists, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that we need backward edges because the augment path that
>   we choose may not contribute to the final max flow.

I think that is not the actual idea. Every flow that you find from source to destination must be contributed to the maximum flow - otherwise, this is not the maximum. We draw the backward edges so that we can correct the selected augmenting paths if there are other flows. I am trying to explain a bit more.

We can find edges from source to destination using DFS or BFS (normal graph traversing algorithm). However, the problem with DFS and BFS is whenever you choose a path, you have the bottleneck capacity of that path - that is the minimum capacity of an edge along that augmenting path. However, you could have flown more into that path using other ways. The backward edges are just enabling you to do so.

I understand that the backward edges are not contributing with the minimum S-T cut, however, the backward edges can contribute to the max flow, otherwise, you cannot correct a path taken arbitrarily using DFS or BFS.

Hope that helps!